# Bluetooth beacons not always discovered

Tags: android, bluetooth, estimote, beacon

With a friend we are making an application which uses Estimote beacons. With this app we want to localize people in a building. Now the thing is that we scan for beacons in range and return the nearest beacon as location. (Ranging beacons)
This works great, but when we asked like 2-3 times the device doesn't find any near beacon anymore. When I just shutdown the Bluetooth and start it up again, my phone finds beacons again. Does anyone knows that issue and has a fix? I guess it's a Bluetooth problem, I asked on estimote forums but hadn't any response so far. If there are some people specialized in Bluetooth/beacons, maybe they have an explanation?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I use a OnePlus One. My friend has a Xiaomi and he has less/no problems.